# WCF virtual method

Tags: wcf

I want to implement a caching mechanism as shown in:
http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2007/08/10/architecture-wcf-services-and-caching.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage
So i do on the service:

```
[OperationContract]
int Test();

IMPLEMENTATION:
public virtual int Test ()
{
    return 1;
}
```

The problem is that the client does not see the method marked as virtual.
Can we or can not override virtual WCF functions?

My bad...now i see the cache was build on server side.

Answer (score 0):

No, the client will not know that the method is virtual since the client is targeting the interface and not the implementation and that is how it should be. Often the service is at someother location so how would it be possible to override something on a different server? What you can and should do is abtracting a way the wcf service in you client and in your class that you abstract you might or might not call the service.

Comment: In that case, how could one moq such a service?

Comment: @Richard I think the answer is that you just mock the interface the service exposes